# Prove that vectors x,y are linearly dependent exactly when ...

Tags: linear-algebra, cross-product

> Prove that vectors $\vec{x},\vec{y}$ (belonging to $\mathbb{R}^3$) are linearly dependent only if the following is true
>   $$
> \begin{vmatrix}
> x_1&y_1
> \\ 
> x_2&y_2
> \end{vmatrix}
> =\begin{vmatrix}
> x_1&y_1
> \\ 
> x_3&y_3
> \end{vmatrix}=\begin{vmatrix}
> x_2&y_2
> \\ 
> x_3&y_3
> \end{vmatrix}
> = 0.
> $$

Could someone give any tips on how to do this?

Comment: I have edited your post to fix up the formatting; you can look at what I did (to see how to do it!) by clicking the "edit" button beneath your post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a 3 by 3 matrix

$$\left[ \begin{array}{ccc} x_1 & y_1 & z_1 \\ x_2& y_2 &z_2 \\ x_3 &y_3 &z_3 \end{array} \right]$$.

Then the determinant of $z$ is given by

$$
 z_3 \Bigl| \begin{array}{cc} x_1 & y_1 \\ x_2 & y_2 \end{array}\Bigr|
 -
 z_2 \Bigl| \begin{array}{cc} x_1 & y_1 \\ x_3 & y_3 \end{array}\Bigr|
+
 z_1 \Bigl| \begin{array}{cc} x_2 & y_2 \\ x_3 & y_3 \end{array}\Bigr|
$$

So given your conditions the determinant of my matrix is zero regardless of the vector $z$ so $x,y$ must be dependent.  Conversely, if $x,y$ are linearly dependent then the determinant of my matrix equals zero for any vector $z$ and hence each of your determinants must be zero.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

$\textbf{x}$ and $\textbf{y}$ are linearly dependent if and only if $\textbf{x}\times \textbf{y} = \textbf{0}$, and

$$
\textbf{x}\times \textbf{y} = \pmatrix{\textbf{e}_1 & \textbf{e}_2 & \textbf{e}_3\\x_1 & x_2 & x_3\\y_1 & y_2 & y_3}
$$

(where $\textbf{e}_n$ is the unit vector in the $n$th dimension)

Alternate hint in absence of cross product:

What happens if $\textbf{x} = a\textbf{y}$ for some constant $a$?

Comment: I am not quite sure if we are allowed to use the cross product as we haven't proved it yet.

Comment: See my edit, it provides an alternate hint.